# What is an spnego Token?

Tags: authentication

Sorry if the spelling is completely wrong.  What the heck is one?  Why is it preventing me from authenticating via Mozilla?  Why would someone force me to use one to authenticate from a command line tool?  How is it tied to the back end being implemented in Silverlight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SPNEGO [Simple and Protected GSSAPI Negotiation Mechanism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPNEGO) is a GSSAPI "pseudo mechanism" that is used to negotiate one of a number of possible real mechanisms.

> SPNEGO's most visible use is in Microsoft's "HTTP Negotiate" authentication extension. It was first implemented in Internet Explorer 5.01 and IIS 5.0 and provided single sign-on capability later marketed as Integrated Windows Authentication. The negotiable sub-mechanisms included NTLM and Kerberos, both used in Active Directory.